# Why does concurrent put to a ConcurrentHashMap not produce the expected result?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

I am trying to test concurrent puts to a `ConcurrentHashMap` using multiple threads, but the size of the map after processing is not what I expected.

I have the following code to insert 1000 entries into a `ConcurrentHashMap`:

```
@Test
public void testThreadSafetyConcurrentHashMap() {
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    Runnable runnable = () -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            map.put(i, i);
        }
    };

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        executorService.submit(runnable);
    }

    System.out.println(map.size());
}
```

I am expecting 1000 items for the `map.size()` call, but I don't get this every time.

Can someone tell me what the problem is? I thought 4 threads putting 1000 items at the same time, would result in a total of 1000 items at the end?

Comment: Are all the runnables done by the time you print the map's size?

Comment: You immediately print the size after starting the threads. They're simply not finished in the short amount of time. Try adding a `Thread.sleep(1000);` before printing and you'll see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`ExecutorService.invokeAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection)) to ensure that all threads are done with their job before the size of the map would be checked.

This method returns *"a list of Futures holding their status and results **when all complete**"*, i.e. it is **blocking** and that's what we need in this case (we are not interested in its return value and it's omitted in the code below).

`invokeAll()` expects a collection of `Callable` and we can use [`Executors.callable()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#callable(java.lang.Runnable)) to convert a `Runnable` into a `Callable`.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    
Runnable runnable = () -> {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        map.put(i, i);
    }
};
    
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

executorService.invokeAll(Collections.nCopies(4, Executors.callable(runnable)));
    
System.out.println(map.size());
```